# Can I import (and repair) damaged GIS shape files?

Tags: import, geography

Five GIS shape files are available online at

http://www.utahcounty.gov/OnlineServices/maps/DataLayers.asp.

Mathematica 10 imports 4 of the 5 files just fine (in the sense that, after download,

```
Import["municipalities.zip", "Graphics"]
```

prints a map with no error messages).  However, the Tax Parcels file (which is by far the largest of the 5) fails with the error message

```
LinkRead::linkep : An unexpected end of packet was received.
```

Assuming that this file is genuinely damaged (and that it wasn't just too big for Mathematica on my computer to handle), is there a way to import such a damaged or incomplete file anyway so that I can fix it within Mathematica?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Just checked, and parcels.zip loads fine into QGIS, so I guess my question is moot.  (Or becomes the question:  Why can't Mathematica import this?)

Comment: Is The Tax Parcels file a graphics or a text or data file?